# Autohotkey, problems redefining keypress down state of mousekey

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I am using the LButton (mouse left) in a keybind as a prefix key. I got it to work, problem is I now need to redefine the LButton as whatever it was in it's natural state...in Autohotkey's terms.
*I read this: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm.*
And cameup with the following code, but it's not working at all the way I thought it would. Simply put, you can use $LButton::Send {Click Left} to emulate the basic mouse click. The problem is when you hold the button/key down, nothing happens. I thought the code to emulate, or define the 'pressed down' behaviour would be readily available, but what I've found isn't working.

```
$LButton::
    if (GetKeyState("LButton", "P"))  
        Send, {Click Left Down} ;tried variants with {Click Left} etc alrdy
    else
        Send, {Click Left Up}

return
```

For person in comments:

```
LButton & ~RButton::
Send, 1{Click Right}{Click Left}{Click Right}{MButton}
Sleep 130 ;125
Send, 1
return

$LButton:: ;no idea what this shud be
SendInput {Click Left}
;Send, {Click Left Down}
;KeyWait, LButton   
;Send, {Click Left Up}
return

RButton::
Send, 1{Click Right}{Click Left}{Click Right}{MButton}
Sleep 130 ;125
Send, 1
return
```

Comment: This is the wrong approach, can you show the hotkey you have which uses LButton so I can recommend a better approach for that case?

Comment: posted to the post

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood this correctly, but you want holding LButton, then clicking the RButton to run this code:

```
Send, 1{Click Right}{Click Left}{Click Right}{MButton}
Sleep 130 ;125
Send, 1
```

And just clicking RButton should run that code as well?
And if LButton is just pressed normally (not in combination with RButton) it should function as normal?

Well this would be it:

```
~LButton & RButton::
RButton::
    Send, 1{Click Right}{Click Left}{Click Right}{MButton}
    Sleep, 130
    Send, 1
return
```

Basically just making use of the [`~` modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde).

Although I can't speak for `Send, 1{Click Right}{Click Left}{Click Right}{MButton}`.
I don't know what it's supposed to do, but maybe/hopefully it's doing the right thing.

Comment: this code generates error messages. RButton:: on its own will set the key to nothing/null. Sends nothing and return is implied. I've not seen any syntax to date that allows u to put a hotkey within a hotkey that will ignore the above.

Comment: Stacking labels is normal AHK syntax. There are no errors in that code. Though now that you made me think about it, the first hotkey is totally redundant, RButton gets clicked anyway, lol. What errors are you supposedly getting?

Comment: my mistake, seems to work as desired when testing sending keys to notepad. isn't working ingame tho. is there a way to maybe freeze the lbutton's functionality at the time of ignition? would need a 600ms freeze or so to get through rbutton's cmds

Answer (score 0):

Pressing w or something that you define should do the job

```
w::
Send, {Click down}
Send, {Blind}1{Click Right}{Click}{Click Right}{MButton}
Sleep 130 ;125
Send, 1
return
```

Anyone looking for something similar could try in this direction

Answer (score 0):

```
#SingleInstance force
#warn

r::Reload
x::ExitApp
w::
Send, {Click down}
Send, {Blind}1{Click Right}{Click}{Click Right}{MButton}
Sleep 130 ;125
Send, 1
return
```

just Pressing w should do the job

> Alternately

, the below one will do the same

```
LButton::Send, {Click down}

RButton::
if GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
{
Send, {Blind}1{Click Right}{Click}{Click Right}{MButton}
Sleep 130 ;125
Send, 1
}
else
Send, {Click Right}
return
```